# What is the best practice of saving an audio file with louder volume?

Tags: audio, mp3, vlc

**I would like to save a quiet audio file with more volume.** Can you suggest me a program, method to do it?

The device I would like to use the audio file on is not very intelligent and the maximum volume setting is too quiet for me. Other audio files (that are louder) can be played fine on the device. So I thought, I open the file on PC, modify it to be louder, save it, then the device will play this fine too. I am aware of distortions and such, that is not the point now.

I have used VLC player and I can make a setting where the audio file is loud enough with little distortions, but I can not find the options to save the file with these settings. It is an MP3 file.

Thanks for the help, 
Sziro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing the volume of an audio file so that the peaks are at (or near) the maximum level is called normalisation. You can use an audio editior like [audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) or [there are dedicated solutions](http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2007/01/04/how-to-normalize-your-mp3-volume-levels-the-right-way/). Normally if saving to mp3 you normalise to slightly less than full volume (say -0.5 dB).

You might also want to consider [compressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range_compression) the audio. This will be useful if the peaks in your audio are much louder than the quiet passages, and the quiet passages are hard to hear as a result. Again, [you can do this in audacity](http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/Compressor).